# Matlab - how to calculate with filename

Tags: matlab

I have files that I have to analize in Matlab. They are starting times of the Recording. What I have to do is calculate the time of an event in specific files. How can I get the time from the file name? How can I change it to a variable without .mp3 at the end?

Comment: Hey, welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take a moment to look over [this guide on how to ask a question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You need to make sure to give enough information in your question so that we can answer it, and make sure to show what you have tried so far. Giving a minimum example that illustrates the problem is helpful too.

Comment: Maybe you want `D = dir('*.mp3')` and `D.date`

Answer (score 0):

In Matlab, the dir function returns information about files in a directory, including the modification date and time. For example:

result = dir ('somefile.mp3');

result.date